# React Native CLI android app is not run in mac android studio

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not add entry '/Users/<--username-->/Documents/myReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.69.3/react-native-0.69.3.pom' to cache md5-checksums.bin (/Users/<--username-->/Documents/myReactNativeApp/android/.gradle/7.3.3/checksums/md5-checksums.bin).
> java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
```

[image: Snapshot of the above error]

package dependencies:
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",

current version:
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.3"

node Version: v16.16.0
react-native-cli Version:  2.0.1
cocoapods Version: 1.11.3
Macbook Air (Mac m1)

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Any intentions to update this question? I think I've run into the exact same issue and have been unable to find a solution lol